# How to target TinyMCE editor for styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tinymce

I feel kind of silly asking this question.  I am simply trying to target the entire TinyMCE editor so I can apply some style to it; for example apply 10px of padding around it.

I am using TinyMCE 4.  If I start with the HTML shown below, TinyMCE will create following HTML.

I wish to target the entire TinyMCE editor which happens to be #mce_9. #mce_9, however, is an ID created by TinyMCE, and I don't want my CSS to have to "know" what ID will be automatically assigned.  TinyMCE's body_id and body_class property allows me to target the internal iframe, not the entire editor.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "#frontContent",
    //body_id:"frontContentWindow"
});
```

HTML before applying TinyMCE

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="frontContent">BLA BLA BLA</div>
</div>
```

HTML after applying TinyMCE

```
<div id="content">
    <div tabindex="-1" hidefocus="1" class="mce-tinymce mce-container mce-panel" id="mce_9" style="visibility: hidden; border-width: 1px; width: 600px;">
        <div class="mce-container-body mce-stack-layout" id="mce_9-body">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="frontContent" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">BLA BLA BLA</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would probably be better off asking this question in the TinyMCE forums, they are really good!! Regardless, have you tried adding a padding to the `#content` element?

Comment: @BenCarey.  I only wish to target the editor (`#mce_9`), and not other elements which might happen to be located in `#content`.

Comment: In that case, place a container around each tinyMCE?

Comment: @BenCarey.  Thanks again Ben, but I have to believe there is a better way.  I can also use jQuery to target the original element `#frontContent`, find it's previous sibling which happens to be `#mce_9`, apply an ID to it, etc, but this also seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming anyone can have two TinyMCE editors, the id isnt specific. The id is generated dynamically. Please use the class  `mce-tinymce` instead of an unique id.

```
<div id="content">
    <div tabindex="-1" hidefocus="1" class="mce-tinymce mce-container mce-panel" id="mce_9" style="visibility: hidden; border-width: 1px; width: 600px;">
        <div class="mce-container-body mce-stack-layout" id="mce_9-body">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="frontContent" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">BLA BLA BLA</div>
</div>

<div id="content2">
    <div tabindex="-1" hidefocus="1" class="mce-tinymce mce-container mce-panel" id="mce_10" style="visibility: hidden; border-width: 1px; width: 600px;">
        <div class="mce-container-body mce-stack-layout" id="mce_10-body">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="frontContent2" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">BLA BLA BLA</div>
</div>

<style>
#content2 .mce-tinymce{
   padding:10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I actually have two TinyMCE editors on the page, but I only want to add padding to one of them.  How can using class `mce-tinymce` differentiate between the two?  Unless I can target a parent of a given editor, but how to do so escapes me.

Comment: Assuming the ids are `content` and `content2` the css applied using `#content .mce-timymce {padding:10px;}` or `#content2 .mce-timymce {padding:10px;}` for the second editor.

Comment: Yes, I understand how I can wrap the tinymce `<div>` in another `<div>`.  It just seems hard to believe this is how it should be done.

Comment: What 'bout a different theme?

Comment: Maybe...  I don't have any experience with themes, but am willing to try.  Or use your wrap another div solution which will work.  I think there probably is some built in method to add an ID to the entire editor, but I can't seem to find it.